# Increment a number and reset counter on the next day

Tags: php, random, token

How do I generate a 4 digit random number at start of the day in PHP and increment it each time the script is executed. And then reset the counter after 24 hours. I don't want to save the random number of some external file or database. So is it possible to achieve this without saving it to some file?

like I generated a number day 2346 now each time my ph script is executed its incremented as
3457
4568
5679 and if it reaches 9999 it loops to 0000

and after 24 hours a new random number is generated.

I am making this to demonstrate some session token vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends what want to accomplish. (Session token vulnerabilities?)

You can always generate a number using [rand()](http://php.net/rand)

If you don't want to save it, you can create a formula to calculate a new number for each day, but then it isn't random anymore.

You can save this number either in a DB or file (or caching mechanisms like APC), but you definitely need something to store the number.

If you need a number per user, you can use the session storage ($_SESSION), although technically the session is a file nevertheless, in most cases ;))

Answer (score 0):

You can store both the number and the date it was generated.  During the day you increment as you're already doing, then if the date is passed (you will check this before incrementing), you will generate a new random number for the new day.

I am curious of your demonstration, though :-)